# Calculating a sum that's taken over all of the k-element subspaces of an n-element space

Tags: summation

Currently I constructed a formula (the idea from which it arose was completely combinatorial, won't bother you with that) and was wondering whether this is applic-able in Mathematica (I've used it so far, primarily for implementation of Numerical Methods and visualisation of ODEs). The idea is as follows:

Given $n \in \mathbb N$ $\setminus ${0,1} and fixing $k \in n \setminus${$\emptyset$} and for each $i \in {\overline{ 1,n}}$ I'm given  the following numbers (they are known) - $L_{i},I_{i}$ and $m_{i}$. And now I want to calculate the following sum (a somewhat "similar" sum, meaning that it's taken over subsets, arises in the Inclusion-Exclusion principle):

$$\sum_{J\subseteq \lbrace 1,...,n \rbrace \\ Card(J)=k} \prod_{i \in J\\j \in \lbrace1,...,n \rbrace \setminus J}(I_j-J_jm_j)L_im_i$$

$Card(J)$ clearly stands for the cardinality of the specific taken subset. It's clear that the above expression will consist of $\binom{n}{k}$ amount of additions, every one of each will consist of $n$ multipliers. This is the formula. Thank you in advance.

p.s. I can construct an Inclusion-Exclusion alike formulation of the above stated sum, I'm asking out of curiosity.

Comment: This is applicable or rather, doable quiet likely...have you tried cosinf yourself? Mathematiica had a nice platte with math symbols implemented for writing code in direct math form, have you tried this?

Comment: Do you know about `Subsets[]` and `Complement[]`? Also `Sum[f[i],{i,{a,b,c}}]`?